# What do the dots on the golden globe at the end of Assassin's Creed signify?

Tags: assassins-creed

After Altair kills his master Al Mualim, the Apple of Eden projects a golden globe like this:

[image]

The entire globe rotates and on it there are many golden dots which keep blinking.

My question: **What do those golden dots signify?**

P.S. I am currently playing AC Brotherhood (and have only played AC 1 apart from that) so please don't spoil any suspense.

Thanks!

Comment: Downvoting for the extreme contradiction. This is obviously a main device in the story. If you ask about story, expect spoilers.

Comment: @Timelord64 your wording suggests that this is specualtion. Yes, it is more than likely a plot point to be revealed later in the storyline, but it doesn't sound like you have much proof. Additionally, I beleive this is perfectly answerable without spoilers, eg: "This was addressed in AC2", or, as it appears in AC2: Brotherhood; "These events (a, b & c) are related to this"

Comment: The only game I havnt played is the latest. It is not speculation, @Ben. It is actual spoilers for the rest of the series.

Comment: I just thought it was obvious to the players who had not played the rest of the series to understand it better.

Comment: Wait, OP are you saying you have only played **the end** of assassins creed 1? Also, in case you wernt aware, brotherhood is the third title. So more spoilers ahoy..

Comment: @Timelord64 to clarify, I was not saying that it *was* speculation, only that it *sounded* as such.

Comment: @Ben, or rather, your speculation, on speculation. OP is literally asking "what does the ending mean, without spoiling the game".

Comment: @Timelord64 I think your answer is perfectly right. It got the point across. It didn't spoil any suspense for future games. It's exactly what I needed. I don't know why you would want to down vote for contradiction or whatever :/

Comment: @Timelord64 And, I have played the entire Assassin's Creed 1 and am at about 25% sync in AC brotherhood. And I know ACB is the third title... I didn't really want to play AC2 so I didn't. And, btw, how would I know - *before asking my question* - that the answer to my question is in AC titles that I haven't played? Now, that you have answered that the answer's in future titles, so I know this now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The golden dots mark artifacts of Eden.

The apple is one of these artifacts. There are many more, several of which are key plot devices for the future Assassin's Creed titles.